# How to make the illustration dynamic while the shapes still connect to each other in Microsoft Excel (with or without VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba, merge, shapes

I want to ask if you know how I can **merge shapes in Excel** in that they **will not overlap** with one another when their dimensions are automatically changed via the VBA program. Initially, the program can help the user adjust the shape size based on the inputted value in the cell selected as written in the VBA.[image]

We tried merging them in the most simple way. Still, the shapes overlap each other when the shape size are changed based on the inputted values. We are expecting that the shapes will maintain their arrangements without overlapping.

Comment: You'd need VBA for this (maybe using the `worksheet_change` event). If length and width can vary independently for each shape though,  what "arrangement" should they keep?  Left-justified? Center-justified?

Comment: Is there a reason for using Excel for this?